# Complete The Square for $x^2-10x+18$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, completing-the-square

Okay so the question is:

$x^2-10x+18$ has to be written in the form $(x-a)^2+b$ and I have to provide the values of $a$ and $b$.

I worked out that $a= -5$ and $b= -7$.

On the video I am watching, he states that $a=+5$ not $-5$, and $b=  -7$. I understand why he got $b = -7$, but how is $a = +5$? when clearly it states in the brackets $(x-5)^2$.

Comment: You know the polynomial equals $(x-5)^2 - 7$.  Plug in $a = 5$ and $b = -7$: $(x-(5))^2 + (-7) = (x-5)^2 - 7$.  It works, so that is the answer.

Comment: You got (-a)=(-5) => a=5 and not (-5)

Answer (score 3):

Because you shall produce an expression $(x-a)^2+b$, not $(x+a)^2+b$.

Comment: then surely let b=+7 ?

Comment: I haven't been taught how to simplify this type of algebra yet, so maybe that is what is putting me off course. However im sure the general formula is (x-a)^2 + b and I have always kept the same symbol after the x and before the a

Answer (score 3):

You have $(x-5)^2-7=(x-a)^2+b$ so that $$-5=-a \text { therefore } a=5$$$$-7=b\text { therefore }  b=-7$$

Until you get used to the signs in these expressions it is worth taking a little extra care and writing the parallel expressions next to one another (or one below the other).

Answer (score 0):

Think of $(x-a)^2+b$ as "($x$ minus a number)$^2$ plus another number" and not just as a template to plug and chug.

What is required in parentheses is "$x$ minus a number", so you need to always write the minus sign, whether the constant $a$ is positive or negative.

for example the following
$$(x-7)^2+3$$
$$(x+9)^2+8$$
$$(x+11)^2-4$$
should be written as
$$(x-(7))^2+(3)$$
$$(x-(-9))^2+(8)$$
$$(x-(-11))^2+(-4)$$
Notice how the $a$ is subtracted and the $b$ is added, otherwise the expression wouldn't be in the form
$(x-a)^2+b$.